# CentOS 7 - Warning: group chinese-support does not exist

Tags: centos7

I installed a CentOS 7 in my VMware workstation, but this os doesn't support Chinese. So I used `yum goupinstall -y chinese-support` to install Chinese Language package. but I got this:

[image]

and I have typed the command `yum -y update`;
What can I do then ?

Answer (score 6):

On Centos 7 `yum groupinstall "fonts"`

Answer (score 1):

I got the same problem. I resolved the problem with the command `yum groupinstall "fonts"`

Answer (score 0):

For most groups hit by this bug, I worked around this by using description with escaped spaces:

```
yum groupinstall Web\ Server
```

worked where

```
yum groupinstall "Web Server" / yum groupinstall web-server
```

failed.